# Best way to refresh user account object stored in session on every request

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple relational database with only 3 tables (one-to-one and a one-to-many relationship), and I need to pull the data from these 3 tables and store int in a POJO object which will be stored in the users session. However, The data in these tables are frequently updated from another application seperate from the webapp, so when the POJO stored in the users session must be updated with the new data upon each request. It is too inefficient to query the database for all the data and construct a new user object upon each request (even with optimized stored procedures). 
So my question is:

**What would be the best method to refresh the user Object with the updated data in the database?**

I have looked at using an ORM framework (specifically hibernate) for persistence between the user object and database, but my concerns are:

- Hibernate seems better suited for newly created applications because of the way hibernate handles the creation of the database schema according to the mapped entity objects
- It might be difficult to configure my persistent objects to conform to my current database schema
- would using hibernate even improve the performance when refreshing the users Account object?
- I have put a good amount of time in creating and optimizing my stored procedures. Would I still be able to utilize them?

I was thinking that I could just create my entity objects exactly how I want them and let hibernate do its thing and create new tables. I would then transfer my current data to the new tables and continue to use hibernate.

I know I don't really have any specific question and that's because I cannot find the best solution to me problem and I don't want to dive into using hibernate then find out it isn't right for my application.

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Hibernate will make it more efficient to refresh the user object from the database. However it could make *you* more efficient at writing DB persitence code.

To go back to the original question, instead of reloading the whole user object on every request, you could use a `version` field. This can be done with or without Hibernate.

First you add a `version` column to your main user table. Each time your webapp or the external application updates the user, it must also increment the `version` by one. Then on every request, you call a small query (or sp) that only returns the `version` of the user. If the version is different from the one stored in the session, you reload the user object, otherwise you don't.

This could improve performance a lot if the user data does not change too often, since the query used to retrieve the version should be very fast. Alternatively, you could use a `last_modified` (timestamp) column instead of a `version` column.

When using Hibernate/JPA, you can use the `@Version` annotation to have Hibernate manage the version field automatically for you. But it can also be done manually without Hibernate.

Comment: Whoa! Excellent idea! This will definitely help because the data will only be updated if the user is also logged onto the separate application (I guess I could also just check and see if they are logged on to that application). Now I guess the question is to use hibernate or not. Do you think it will be beneficial for my case? Would I be better off letting hibernate create the tables from the objects? or should I attempt to make it use my current schema?

Comment: If you plan to extend your app and add more tables in the future, it could be worth it. Hibernate and JPA are quite flexible and can adapt to almost any existing schema. But if everything is already developped and working, maybe it's not worth it. As some people say, if it's not broken, don't fix it. It could be interesting as a learning experience though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend:

- Use EJB entities to store the user information
- Ensure all applications that change/load user information do so through your EJB session beans
- Don't "cache" the user information in HTTP session: load it on every single request
- Apply EJB 2nd-level caching to your user information entities

With this approach, the database is never read, unless the cache is flushed or the application is redeployed.